# Connect to mongodb server with mongoDB Compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB on my Ubuntu server by using MongoDB compass. Somehow I keep getting the underneath error.

[the error i get in MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNz7v.png)

My mongodb is running and listining on Port 27017

[Connection to MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exr65.png)

What could be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running mongodb on your local host machine? 
if yes , please fill the first filed "Hostname" with localhost

Comment: No, it runs on the server

Comment: Is the port 27017 open on the server ?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error text and the connection information, rather than linking to screenshots? It would make your question easier to read, and is particularly relevant to getting it indexed to make it more findable etc.

Comment: This is the MongoDB Compass error:
Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port.

Unfortunately the connection information is too long to paste in this comment.

This is the connection string:
mongodb://guidovdriet:<password>@45.77.98.181:27017/buildings_of_rotterdam?authSource=admin

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda, Yes it is..

Comment: What version of Compass are you using?